# TYPO3 8 dbal mapping with other server

Tags: mysqli, typo3, adodb, dbal

I've a problem.
I just installed a new TYPO3 8 with adodb and dbal extensions.

Now I have an other server with a MySQLi Server and some custom tables in one database.

I want to show and edit the data from that other MySQLi Server Database Table named account in my TYPO3. For that, I have created my own extension with an model named tx_base_domain_model_account with as example 2 fields.

After that I created a dbal mapping with the following configuration:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['dbal'] = array(
'handlerCfg' => array(
    '_DEFAULT' => array(
        'type' => 'native',
        'config' => array(
            'driver' => 'mysqli'
        )
    ),
    '_otherServer' => array(
        'type' => 'native',
        'config' => array(
            'username' => 'username',
            'password' => 'password',
            'host' => '192.168.177.XX',
            'database' => 'account',
        )
    ),
),
'table2handlerKeys' => array(
    'account' => '_otherServer'
),
'debugOptions' => array(
    'enabled' => true,
    'printErrors' => true,
    'EXPLAIN' => 1,
    'parseQuery' => 1,
    'joinTables' => 1
),
'mapping' => array(
    'tx_base_domain_model_account' => array(
        'mapTableName' => 'account',
        'mapFieldNames' => array (
            'uid' => 'id',
            'pid' => 119,
            'login' => 'login',
            'password' => 'password',
            'cruser_id' => 1
        )
    )
)
```

);

But I can't see, edit or whatever the data from that other server database table.
Can you help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

With the switch to doctrine-dbal in core v8, the core extensions 'dbal' and 'adodb' have been obsoleted. See https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Database/Configuration/Index.html for configuration details on how to map tables to a different dbms using doctrine-dbal.